# How to change Text property of TextBlock in between animations?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, animation

My WPF app has animation along these lines:

a. Rotate a TextBlock from 000 to 090.

b. Update the Text property of the TextBlock to a new value

c. Continue rotating the TextBlock from 090 to 180.

I am able to achieve steps a and c, by adding two DoubleAnimations to the Children of a StoryBoard.  Is there a way to trap the end of the first animation to do some work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two storyboards, one for the rotate to 90 and the other to 180. When the first storyboard completes, update the text, then start the next storyboard.

```
Storyboard rotateTo90 = new Storyboard();
// Add rotate animation
rotateTo90.Completed += (s,e) => 
    { 
         TextBlock1.Text = "Updated";
         Storyboard rotateTo180 = new Storyboard();
         // Add rotate animation
         rotateTo180.Begin();
    };
rotateTo90.Begin();
```

Answer (score 3):

[For .NET Framework 4.5 and above]

You could use the [StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.stringanimationusingkeyframes?view=netframework-4.5) class to modify the text using DiscreteStringKeyFrame. Following is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-string-by-using-key-frames).

```
<Button Name="myAnimatedButton" Margin="200"
      FontSize="16pt" FontFamily="Verdana">Some Text
      <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                Storyboard.TargetName="myAnimatedButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Content)"
                Duration="0:0:8" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">

                <!-- All the key frames below are DiscreteStringKeyFrames. Discrete key frames create 
                sudden "jumps" between values (no interpolation). Only discrete key frames can be used 
                for String key frame animations. -->
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="A" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="An" KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Ani" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Anim" KeyTime="0:0:2.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Anima" KeyTime="0:0:3" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animat" KeyTime="0:0:3.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animate" KeyTime="0:0:4" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated" KeyTime="0:0:4.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated " KeyTime="0:0:5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated T" KeyTime="0:0:5.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Te" KeyTime="0:0:6" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Tex" KeyTime="0:0:6.5" />
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Animated Text" KeyTime="0:0:7" />
              </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>              
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger> 
      </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Thanks to the latest additions to the collection of animations in .NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames and use it to set the value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745819.aspx